# extract path value substring using sed

Tags: bash, sed

Trying to extract text between a path variable which has the following value
`path_value="path/to/value/src"`
I want to extract just `value` from the above variable and use that later in my script. I know it can be done using `grep` or `awk` but I wanted to know how it can be done using `sed`

So I tried this
`service_name=$(echo $path_value | sed -e 's/path/to/(.*\)/.*/\1/')`
But I get this error `bad flag in substitute command: '('`

Could you please suggest what is the right regex to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
path_value="path/to/value/src"
service_name=$(echo "$path_value" | sed 's~path/to/\([^/]*\)/.*~\1~')
echo "$service_name"
# => value
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/YUlnOT).

Note I replaced `/` regex delimiters with `~` so as to avoid escaping `/` chars inside the pattern.

The capturing parentheses must both be escaped in a POSIX BRE regex.

The `[^/]*` part only matches zero or more chars other than `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) and eliminating the subprocess calls:

```
$ path_value="path/to/value/src"

$ tempx="${path_value%/*}"
$ echo "${tempx}"
path/to/value

$ service_name="${tempx##*/}"
$ echo "${service_name}"
value
```

Performing a `bash/regex` comparison and retrieving the desired item from the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array (also eliminates subprocess calls):

```
$ regex='.*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'
$ [[ "${path_value}" =~ $regex ]] && service_name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
$ echo "${service_name}"

# fwiw, contents of the BASH_REMATCH[] array:

$ typeset -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="path/to/value/src" [1]="value" [2]="src")
```